# Implementing Content Security Policy with Google Tag Manager

Tags: php, http, backend, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I am struggling with implementing google services in CSP. It is for my website https://maxwink.com. The website is built with custom php.

The directives I used are

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.googletagmanager.com  https://tagmanager.google.com/ https://*.google.com;"
```

## The errors are

1. `Error with Permissions-Policy header: Parse of permissions policy failed because of errors reported by structured header parser.`
2. `The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'Content-Security-Policy:' contains one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names.`
3. `Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXX' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`
4. `Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

I request you to help me out on this. I am completely lost

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the main problem is that you have 2 different content security policies defined, and another one commented out.

You set this response header:

```
content-security-policy: Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.googletagmanager.com  https://tagmanager.google.com/ https://*.google.com;
```

You set this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

This meta tag is commented out

```
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' googletagmanager.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' googletagmanager.com *.hotjar.com img-src: www.googletagmanager.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'none'"> -->
```

The problems are:

1. With multiple policies content needs to pass ALL policies, adding more only makes it stricter. Use only one policy unless there is some advanced scenario you need multiple policies to solve.
2. You have included the text "Content-Security-Policy:" inside the value of the policy given in the header, this should be the name of the header, not in the content.

In case you use the commented out policy, remove the colon in "img-src:"

Comment: Hi Halvor. I Removed the meta tag, and updated the response header to 

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' google-analytics.com *.hotjar.com googletagmanager.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' google-analytics.com *.hotjar.com googletagmanager.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' google-analytics.com *.hotjar.com googletagmanager.com; font-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'"`

Still getting the same error. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Seems like you removed the meta tag that was commented out, there is still an active one that is likely the cause of many errors as it doesn't allow any external sources.

Comment: Hi! I revised my entire **.htaccess** directives but there is nowhere else I have implemented CSP. Above the CSP declaration I have declared **permission-policy**. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: Response headers could be also be added by webservers, proxies, frameworks etc. Check their configuration also as it doesn't seem like it is the default value.